# Nested list to unique set based on entity equals

Tags: java, graph-theory

I found the bottleneck of my Kruskal-implementation. I need to convert a

```java
List<List<Edge<T extends Comparable<T>>>> adjacencyList;
// This looks like this: get(0) = [Edge:{Vertex V0, Vertex V1, T weight}, Edge:{Vertex V0, Vertex V2, T weight}, ...]
// and get(indexOf(Vertex V1)) = [{Vertex V1, Vertex V0}, ...]
// obviously indexOf(Vertex) does not comply with type Edge, but the idea is that the index of the Edge where the Vertex otherFirst is the getFrom() is retrieved.
```

to a unique list of edges (see equals method for reference of equality). I need to optimise this and potentially replace with a more efficient solution. The solution should look like this:

```java
get(0) = Edge:{Vertex V0, Vertex V1, T weight}
// there is no element which is Edge:{Vertex V1, Vertex V0, T weight}
```

My current solution looks like this:

```java
private List<Edge<T>> toAdjacencyList(final List<List<Edge<T>>> edges) {
    List<Edge<T>> flat = edges.parallelStream().flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    final Set<Edge<T>> unique = new HashSet<>();
    unique.addAll(flat);
    return new ArrayList<>(unique);
}
```

- Running this against a 1000 vertex, 1000 edge input takes 5ms.
- Running this against a 1000 vertex, 10000 edge input takes 780ms.
- Against a 1000 vertex, 100 000 edge input takes X seconds. I do not know. (And this is what I need to work).

The actual Kruskal-algorithm after the data-caching takes much less than one second.

How do I optimise this, or alternatively, replace this with?

Note: two edges being equal means that Edge:{V1, V0, 10f} and Edge:{V0, V1, 10f} are the same. I am positive that this works.

Answer (score 0):

I had incorrectly implemented the equals method, however, I had forgotten to include Vertex from and Vertex to in the hashCode, if anyone ever has a similar problem.